# Mediawiki-PHP: Check if an article belongs to a category

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm editing a Mediawiki extension (PageCreationNotif) to send mail when a page is added to a certain category.
The extension original code is here: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EPCN/browse/master/

The function I'm working on (onArticleInsertComplete in PageCreationNotif.hooks.php) takes a ( &$article ) as input parameter.
I want to execute the function code only if $article belongs to "Project" category, already created.

Could you provide me the right code snippet to do this?

It would be like (pseudocode):

```
public static function onArticleInsertComplete(&$article){

    if( $article.belongsTo(Category.Project) ){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything like a `belongsTo()` method in the WikiPage class, so you have to iterate over the categories yourself, checking for membership:

```
public function onArticleInsertComplete( WikiPage &$article ) {
    $inCat = false;
    foreach ( $article->getCategories() as $cat) {
        if ( $cat->getText() === "Project" ) {
            $inCat = true;
        }
    }
    if ( $inCat ) {
        // Send email etc.
    }
}
```

(Code is not tested.)

**Update:** Actually, re-reading your question, I think you're better off hooking in to [CategoryAfterPageAdded](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/CategoryAfterPageAdded):

```
Hooks::register( 'CategoryAfterPageAdded', function( Category $category, WikiPage $page ) {
    if ( $category->getTitle()->getBaseText() === 'Project' ) {
        // Send email.
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the code doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried a similar version on my own some days ago, the only difference is the "===" instead of "==", but no mail arrived.
Maybe there are some general steps of the extension that I do not catch.

Comment: I've updated my answer. There may be a delay in when a page gets added to a category, in some situations; make sure you run all jobs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem!! Mediawiki is a wonderful machine